# How to parse every object in my array in json in java without using loop?

Tags: java, mysql, json, playframework

i have data in json format like this :

```
{
  "father" :"Conor",
  "children" : [
      {
          "name":"Cindy",
          "age": 11
      },
      {
          "name":"Heart",
          "age" :12
      },
      {
          "name":"Cindy",
          "age" :13
      }
  ]
}
```

My problem now is how will i going to check every object in the array children if there is name and age field. Currently, i looped it out to check if those two field is supplied/exist, which slows down my app(especially when inserting to database). Is there a way where i don't have to loop it out?

Comment: If it is not there it will throw an error, isn't it?what is the json parser you are using?

Comment: Hmmm... See ur code

Comment: yes. but also one of my problem is that what if there are 1 million objects in there, do i have to check the object one by one?i think its a big problem..

Comment: If you have one million objects you could, and should, distribute this work over a lot of workers.

Comment: this is my code : 
JsonNode childrenNode = requestBody.get("children");

for(JsonNode children: childrenNode)
      if(childrenNode.findValue("name") == null){
          //my error message here
      }
      if(childrenNode.findValue("age") == null){
          //my error message here
      }
}

Comment: actually i have 50,000 data to insert. :D

Comment: You can use schema and validate using jaxb,check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16446308/jaxb-how-to-validate-nillable-and-required-field-when-unmarshalling)

Comment: :D i did not understand. it talks about xml things. i have to read this again and again. thanks for this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JsonPath api in your java code and it provides various filters over the stream of json array. You can give it a try

https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath